# Test APP Receipt Expiration Date (for Apple VPP)a

Tags: ios, testing, app-store, storekit, apple-vpp

I'm trying to test APP Receipt Expiration Date (for VPP) but I'm not able to find how to receive such a receipt from the Sandbox.

Do someone already achieved to test it?

Comment: According to documentation initializing the **SKReceiptRefreshRequest** with **- initWithReceiptProperties:** instead of just **- init** and passing a dictionary of options should generate a Receipt for VPP but, when I use it I do not receive any receipt and even no login to the App Store is requested, **requestDidFinish:** is invoked and no receipt is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. My iPad was caching the login to the App Store. To test and receive the correct test receipt (see my note above) it is necessary to go each time into the General preferences and logout the user before the test.